# Phonegap: Windows Phone hides splash screen too quickly

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

We developed an app with phonegap which runs good on android and ios but has a glitch on windows phone.
The splash screen shows up for a short time and hides with a transition to black. After some seconds  the app starts in the expected behavior.
The black pause is really annoying. Did anybody have come to grips with this problem?.
I am not sure if this is a new problem or the question is already solved but I am not able to fine a solution till now.

Comment: You are likely overriding the built in splash screen functionality. Are you able to open the Windows Phone version solution?

Answer (score 1):

When the app is started, it shows the splashscreen animation paging in; 
the screen turns black  (and the debug console shows up that scripts, grafics, data are loading) and when finished, the splashscreen appears again with paging out animation. 
The app appears and does work correctly.

Shouldn't there be a splashscreen still picture where the screen shows black? (for at least 6 to 8 seconds)

Comment: Same problem here with Cordova 4.0 and WP8. No solutions yet ?